# Invalid IL code

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I update Unity and then updated my project from 5.2.4 to 5.3.4. I then updated some assets from the asset store. I got most of the issues worked out. One continues to elude me.

```
[Exception] InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in com.combatcoding.pso.CommLink:SupplyResource (string,int): IL_0002: call      0x06001fda
0. ResourceNeeded.OnClick() at Assets/_PSO/Scripts/ResourceNeeded.cs:85
1. UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke() at          C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:144
2. UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke() at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:621
3. UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke() at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:756
4. UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke() at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53
5. UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press() at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35
6. UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick() at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44
7. UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute() at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52
8. UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler]() at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269
9. UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update()
```

I don't know where to start fixing this. I can't figure out what's actually wrong at this point.

Can anybody get me pointed in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Is this error from Editor, Windows Build, Mobile?

Comment: What's on `Assets/_PSO/Scripts/ResourceNeeded.cs` line 85?

Comment: This error is shown in the Unity editor during runtime. It happens when a method is executed on a button click.

<code>    ResourceNeeded.OnClick() at Assets/_PSO/Scripts/ResourceNeeded.cs:85

    85:  Commlink.SupplyResource(ID, Player.FactionNumber);</code>